Altium: Change Room number
Is there a way to interchange the position of a room with another of the same type? I don't want to move components.
In my design I already have placed the room in order (0,1,2...), but later I want to be (0,2,4..).

The 'Design > Rooms > Arrange' option only allow me to do it in ascending or descending order.

This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

You might try the swap components feature, but I don't think this applies to rooms.
If you have the rooms also with corresponding rooms in the schematic, you might be able to swap them from the schematic side by going to the Component links (Project->Component links)
When in component links:
Move each room you want to swap to the left, then relinking swapping them and then move them back to the right. Then go back to the schematic and do a design update. They should swap the designators and rooms.
